# DNS name forwarding basic setup issue

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, cname-record

I have provisioned a VPS host server and have a running web app on it. I purchased a domain name on namesilo, now I want to direct traffic to my site not namesilo.
In namesilo I have the following record only (No CNAME, no AAAA record...):

```
hostname: example.com
Type: A
Address/Value: nnn.nnn.nn.nnn  #VPS server IP address
Distance: NA
TTL: 7202
```

In a terminal I tried:

```
nslookup
set type=ns
example.com
>Server: 127.0.1.1
>Non-Authoritative answer:
>example.com nameserver = ns1.dnsowl.com  #namesilo default nameserver

server
set type=a
example.com
>Address: nnn.nnn.nn.nnn  #correct VPS server address

set type=cname
www.example.com
>Server: 127.0.1.1
>Non-authoritative answer:
>www.example.com canonical name = parking.namesilo.com
```

I am totally stumped by the terminology (cname, hostname etc) and not sure how I can get my site pointed at my VPS server so that when the user types in www.example.com it redirects to my website. In VPS server docs they mention CNAME is for when you want to direct another address to your site eg www.example.net -> www.example.com. So I don't think I need a CNAME, yet namesilo seems to be redirecting my site to it's parked spot.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest a book on basic DNS... if you want www.mysite to resolve, you'll need a record for it.

Comment: @Ward thanks, it's it seems like with all the downvotes my question is too basic for this site. Back to the books then for me. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want www.domain.tld to work you will have to setup a new record for it.
You can do this by using a CNAME and pointing it to domain.tld (the existing A record) or by creating a new A record and pointing it to the IP of your VPS.

- A records should point to your VPS IP
- AAAA records are the same, but for IPv6
- CNAME records point to another existing [sub.]domain.tld
- MX records tell the world what host handles your email.

Have you tried looking at the namesilo support pages?
https://www.namesilo.com/Support/DNS-Manager should be a good start.

Also searching for "DNS records" using google will give you everything you need.

Comment: Thanks nStensen. Yes namesilo support was the first place I want but I found the terminology very confusing and I was not clear on exactly what to put under the hostname (ie prefix with www or not?), what they mean by using their nameserver vs VPS nameserver..., how to set up MX. I'll keep researching.

Comment: I found this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-dns-terminology-components-and-concepts

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways I found to go about this. Assuming you are using ip4 (dots between numbers in server ip address):

1) If you want to use namesilo DNS resolution (ie translate mywebsite.com to ip address of server):

In namesilo go to Manage DNS. Delete all resource records and create two new resource records:

```
Hostname: (leave empty) Type:A Address: server_ip_address (eg nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn)  (this will create an A record for mysite.com)
Hostname: www Type: A Address: server_ip_address   (this will create an A record for www.mysite.com)
```

2) If your VPS provider provides a DNS service and you want to use that service for DNS resolution:

Configure A names with your VPS host (one for mysite.com and one for www.mysite.com).
In namesilo select Domain, go to Change nameservers, change the      ns1-3.dnsowl.com name servers to the VPS nameservers.

see https://www.namesilo.com/Support/NameServer-Manager
and https://www.namesilo.com/Support/Point-Domain-to-an-IP-Address